# How do I hide the CMD window that is created as a result of this process?

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

I am trying to run an executable file as part of my program which will be repeatedly called as the within an event handler. 
At the moment, the first and last lines which are commented out run the executable as they should, the issue I am having is trying to make it so that the user has the option to hide this executable as it pops up (done with a radio button)

```
Console.WriteLine("Generated Instruction: " + arguments);                           
             //var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(chartLocation + @"\MODUS CHaRT CMD.exe", arguments ); // Run Command Line instruction
            Process myProc = new Process();

            if (hideChartStatus)  /* make the process invisible */
            {
                try
                {
                    myProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    myProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Invisible CHART window generated");
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not hide CHaRT window");
                }                
            }
            else
            {
                myProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            }

            myProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = chartLocation;
            myProc.StartInfo.FileName = "\\MODUS CHaRT CMD.exe";
            myProc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            myProc.Start();

            //myProc = myProc.Start(chartLocation + @"\MODUS CHaRT CMD.exe", arguments);
            //proc.WaitForExit();
            myProc.WaitForExit();
```

This is what I've got so far but I'm getting the error
" System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified' "

at myProc.start();

I'm guessing it's something to do with how I'm using filename and working directory?

Anyone know the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me everybody,  I'm an idiot.

Basing it more accurately on what is done here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2

The correct use is:

```
//myProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = chartLocation;
            myProc.StartInfo.FileName = chartLocation + @"\MODUS CHaRT CMD.exe";
            myProc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            myProc.Start();
```

Comment: To hide the window try `myProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`